# Elasticsearch - add analyzer while querying with query_string?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using query_string to query elasticsearch with added fuzziness, proximity searches and OR condition.

Is it possible to add analyzer along with query_string while querying based on type of keyword???

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @MayurBuragohain , I was generating the query string dynamically. So, dependency on the type of keywords used to generate query string, I wanted to set the analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test/user/_search? -d '{
"query" : { "match" : {"myField" : {"query" :"test search","analyzer" :
"lowercase_keyword" }} } }'
```

You may specify the analyzer in the query as above.

Comment: Thanks!. I will try that.